# Attempt to do a two way binding results in "cannot be inverted error"

Tags: java, android, data-binding

Hi I am trying to do a two way binding. Property I am trying to bind to in XML file is.

```
android:visibility="@={chart.ShowProgress ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

In the file ChartViewModel file:

```
private int mShowProgress = View.GONE;

public int getShowProgress() {
    if (mColor.colorId == mColorId) {
        return mShowProgress;
    }
    mShowProgress = View.GONE;
    return mShowProgress;
}

public void setShowProgress(@NonNull int isProgressVisible) {
    this.mShowProgress = isProgressVisible;
}
```

However, when I try to build I get error

```
The expression '((chartShowProgress) ? (android.view.View.VISIBLE) : 
(android.view.View.GONE))' cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding

Details: The condition of a ternary operator must be constant: 
android.databinding.tool.writer.KCode@18e15570
```

Please can someone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: hi, have you imported the `View` class in your layout?

Comment: Hi @Zain, yes. I have implemented a CharViewModel class. I have updated my question to include this information.

Comment: excuse me I mean adding this `<import type="android.view.View"/>` wrapped into `<layout><data>` tag

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Yes.I have imported it in side layout.                                                                         
    <data>
        <variable
            name="chart"
            type="com.viewmodels.ChartViewModel"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>

Comment: I can't see the @BindingAdapter annotation.. Can you provide it

Comment: @Zain. I might be missing that. What do I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, my fault I thought you access the boolean via a BindingAdapter, but can you show  `chart.ShowProgress ` in code ?

Comment: I do not have a ShowProgress fn in ChartViewModel file. What should I include in it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JayHawk I tried to mimic your issue with a simple example, I exactly got the error you got, please check the answer, and welcome to discuss more if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, and the reason that you got this error is that you are trying to use a two-way data binding with a ternary expression.

```
android:visibility="@={chart.ShowProgress ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

And this is the normal behavior to see this error, because the the two-way data binding is intended not only to map values from java into XML layouts, but also map them from XML back to their stores in java. So according to your expression you want to map the value of the boolean `chart.ShowProgress` to the visibility of some widget; but how to make the reverse as of mapping XML back to java (how to map visibility of a widget back to java using this ternary expression `chart.ShowProgress ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE` .. the answer you can't do that using the two-way data binding, and that is why this exception is raised.

So to solve your issue, you need to remove the equal sign from the expression, so it should be:

```
android:visibility="@{chart.ShowProgress ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64596538/android-two-way-databinding-problem-of-ternary-operator-must-be-constant Thank you.